# Clicking on active / oldest / votes causes full postback please ajaxify

Tags: feature-request, answers, sorting, ajax

I was looking at a question that had a couple of answers.  I decided to play with the tabs "active", "oldest", and "votes".  I'm not sure why this part isn't making an ajax call to reload the data.  The entire page reloads when you click one of these tabs:

[image]

Can someone please ajaxify this so that the page doesn't flicker.  The ajax request could simply pass the sort order and refresh the contents of the answers?

Comment: No need to AJAXify that. Just simply sort on the browser.

Comment: @PatrickHofman That doesn't work anymore if there's more than one page of answers.